# Sympy Function with string

Tags: sympy, subclass

I would like to have a custom class which in principle behaves like a sympy `Function` but holds also a string. However, when I create a derived class from sympy Function the following code produces an error ('could not parse 'a b'):

```py
import sympy as sp
class testClass(sp.Function):
    pass
a = testClass('a b')
```

I understand that the sympify function is called and has problems to parse 'a b' to a sympy expression. As a possible workaround for my needs I found that

```py
a = testClass(sp.Symbol('a b'))
```

would work. Nevertheless, it would be interesting to avoid the use of Symbol here. In my understanding, to make this working I would have to reimplement the `__new__` method. Is this correct or is there an easy solution?

Comment: What is wrong with using a symbol?

Comment: In principle it is not a problem, but it would be nice to avoid this extra user input.

Comment: You could also define `__new__` and have it convert a string into a symbol.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comment of Oscar Benjamin the following works for me:

```py
import sympy as sp
class testClass(sp.Function):
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        new_args = (sp.Symbol(x) if isinstance(x, str) else x for x in args)
        return super().__new__(cls, *new_args, **kwargs)
    # other methods...

c = testClass('a b')
```